# how to return one of two types of custom table view cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am migrating some objective-c code to Swift. I was able to do something very similar to this in objective-c but it is telling me that I have a "Use of unresolved identifier 'tableViewCell'"; returning it in the method doesn't help.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mainTV.registerClass(EKMenuHeaderCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuHeaderCell")
    self.mainTV.registerClass(EKMenuItemCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MenuItemCell")
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let tmpTableItem = self.tableItems[indexPath.row]
  if let menuHeader = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuHeader {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuHeaderCell
    tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuHeader)
    // return tableViewCell    // doesn't work
  } else if let menuItem = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuItem {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuItemCell
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuItem)
    // return tableViewCell    // doesn't work
  }
  return tableViewCell
}
```

How would I return two different types of custom cells like this in Swift 1.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning `tableViewCell` at the end of the method, but your two variables for `tableViewCell` are scoped to the `if` consequent and `if` alternate - thus invisible at the `return`

To fix it you'll need to ensure that you return a UITableViewCell *in all paths through your code* or you fatal.  So, for example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let tmpTableItem = self.tableItems[indexPath.row]

  if let menuHeader = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuHeader {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuHeaderCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuHeaderCell
    tableViewCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuHeader)
    return tableViewCell

  } else if let menuItem = tmpTableItem as? EKMenuItem {
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MenuItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EKMenuItemCell
    tableViewCell.updateCell(menuItem)
    return tableViewCell
  }

  // If you can return something meaningful, do so; otherwise fatal.
  else { preconditionFailure ("unexpected cell type") }
}
```

Comment: hmmm... so the problem is that cellForRowAtIndexPath is returning an UITableViewCell and will not compile; this is how I did it in obj-c and then at the end did `return nil` but Swift is more fussy (which is probably a good thing)

Comment: You can't return `nil` because the return type is `UITableViewCell` - it must be a cell; it is not an `Optional`.  So, every path must ensure that a `UITableViewCell` is returned or there is no return - aka, a fatal.

Comment: yeah, let me just create a generic one there and see what happens.

Comment: yeah that adding a generic tableViewCell at the end solved it like     `let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    return tableViewCell`

Comment: Except that will fail at runtime if you don't have a cell identified as `"TableViewCell"`.  Just fatal.